# How to update records through controls using ASP.NET with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

```
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, UserName = ?, Password = ?, EmailId = ? where UserId=?", con))
    {


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OdbcType.Int).Value = IntUesrId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = LastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = EmailId;

        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", IntUesrId) ;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", ObjUserProp.FirstName);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", ObjUserProp.LastName) ;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", ObjUserProp.UserName);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", ObjUserProp.Password) ;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", ObjUserProp.EmailId) ;

        con.Open();

        Isdone=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return Isdone;
```

I'm trying to update record using above code then without showing any error it will not update the records

Comment: Make sure you have a valid row against the query parameter IntUesrId in your table and you are passing the right values.

Answer (score 0):

You're never committing the changes to the database.

You need to start a transaction, and then once you perform your update, commit the transaction in order for the changes to be persisted.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctransaction.aspx

Comment: COMMIT is not necessary in this case AFAIK. OP is not creating any transaction , he is simply updating.

Comment: @CodeBuzz and how are those changes persisted?  We use Oracle, but the same pattern above, and if you don't commit the changes, the changes never persist to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints and try debugging your code block . Make sure you have a valid row against the query parameter **IntUesrId** in your table and you are passing the right values. My guess is that you don't have any value set for the update query parameter (**IntUesrId** ) .

Answer (score 0):

You are building your parameters incorrectly.

```
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?, UserName = ?, Password = ?, EmailId = ? where UserId=?", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OdbcType.Int).Value = IntUesrId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = LastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = EmailId;
    }
```

This should be more like:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(@"UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = ?firstName, LastName = ?lastName, UserName = ?userName, Password = ?password, EmailId = ?email where UserId=?userId", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?firstName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = FirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?lastName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = LastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?userName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = UserName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?password", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Password;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = EmailId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?UserId", OdbcType.Int).Value = IntUesrId;
}
```

The main issue being that you are never finding the correct user to update as you are setting the `WHERE` clause with their email address, not their user id. So no, it most likely won't error out.